Error Running Puppeteer on Google App Engine
I need some help running puppeteer on the app engine standard environment to generate pdfs. I have tried several configurations and followed the documentation but I can't get it to work.
Below is my latest configuration:

I have file named ".puppeteerrc.cjs.js" in the root directory with the code below:

const {join} = require('path')


/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.puppeteer_cache')
}


I have created a folder in the node modules directory for cache named ".puppeteer_cache"

In the package.json file I have the following and listed puppeteer as a dependency


  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "gcp-build": "npx @puppeteer/browsers install chrome"
  }

"puppeteer": "^23.11.1"


I have the following code to generate pdfs.

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')


async function generatePDFromUrl(url) {

  // Launch Puppeteer
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox'] // Required for Google Cloud
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage()

  // Navigate to the URL
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

  // Generate PDF
  const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
    format: 'A4', // Paper size
    printBackground: true, // Include background styles
  })

  // Close the browser
  await browser.close()

  return pdfBuffer
}

module.exports = { generatePDFromUrl }

I receive the following error:
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 131.0.6778.204). This can occur if either 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npx puppeteer browsers install chrome) or 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /root/.cache/puppeteer). For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.

You can add the Puppeteer browser dependencies explicitly in your App Engine app.yaml file.

Take a look at this SO response. Also check the comments under it.


I have file named ".puppeteerrc.cjs.js"

According to documentation, the file should be named .puppeteerrc.cjs i.e. there's no .js extension.
